# Placing the submit button of Gravity Forms in center under form

Tags: html, css, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to position the submit button from Gravity Forms under my current form in the center.

Example:

[image]

I have a `two-column` layout on my Gravity Form. The button is currently floating under the right column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @athimohan Its all the default code of Gravity Forms.

Comment: I think you can use margin: 0 auto for the button to be in the center

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: @AldinJuko Gravity Forms automatically generates HTML. It's a mess to post.

Comment: @athimohan Hmm, doesn't seem to do much unfortunately

Comment: @Chris Are you using Bootstrap by any chance?

Comment: @ZombieChowder Yes I am

Comment: @Chris did my solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Laf8/

You basically put your button in a div:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
With the following styles:

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
```